# Exercise from Terence Tao

Tags: real-analysis

In the exercise below I don't understand why Exercise 13.5.9 doesn't contradict 13.5.8 ?[image]

Comment: What about your working out suggests that it *does* contradict 13.5.8?

Comment: Seems contradictory to me.  Is there a word or two missing somewhere?

Comment: Yeah I went to errata I couldn't find any missing word or phrase.

Answer (score 6):

Exercise 13.5.9 is wrong as stated.  A topological space in which every sequence has a convergent subsequence is said to be **sequentially compact**.  Not every compact space is sequentially compact.

EDIT: Exercise 13.5.8 is also wrong.  This is not compact!  Let $S = \{x_i: i \in \mathbb N\}$ be a sequence of distinct points of $X \backslash \{\infty\}$, and consider the open cover $\{U_i: i \in \mathbb N\}$ where $U_i = S^c \cup \{i\}$.  This has no finite subcover.

Comment: So sequentially is missing from the second exercise?  Then it’s right?

Answer (score 2):

There are corrections [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-ii/) to both of these exercises.

> p. 390: Exercise 13.5.8 should be replaced as follows: “Show that
>   there exists an uncountable well-ordered set $\omega_1+1$ that has a
>   maximal element $\infty$, and such that the initial segments $\{ x \in\omega_1+1: x < y \}$ are countable for all $y \in \omega_1+1 \backslash \{\infty\}$.   (Hint: Well-order the real numbers using Exercise
>   8.5.19, take the union of all the countable initial segments, and then adjoin a maximal element $\infty$.)  If we give $\omega_1+1$ the order
>   topology (Exercise 13.5.5), show that $\omega_1+1$ is compact; however,
>   show that not every sequence has a convergent subsequence.”

and

> p. 438, Exercise 13.5.9: One needs to assume as an additional
>   hypothesis that X is first countable, which means that for every x in
>   X there exists a countable sequence V_n of neighborhoods of x, such
>   that every neighbourhood of x contains one of the V_n.